# ExpressionEngine content based on url segment

Tags: expressionengine

I'm just learning EE and I have the following example url, http://mydomain.com/work/preview/clientname

where I want *clientname* to match a channel field I have setup ("client_name") and to pull in channel content only if it matches that channel field.

For example, http://mydomain.com/work/preview/google, would display channel content if the specified channel field "client_name" for a particular entry is "google".

I know how to use the following to pull in content from the channel "videos":

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

...but how do I accomplish this for different url segments?

Comment: You might want to move this question to the the EE StackExchange site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [searching the channel entries tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name) by field name.

Here's an example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos" search:client_name="google"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Do keep in mind though if you want to use the segment for this you'll likely have to pass the segment through an embed as a variable. You can [read about this here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/embedding.html).

Answer (score 0):

Making this change works for me:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos" dynamic="no" search:client_name="segment_2"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```